# Невозможно подключить хранилище cloudant к ibm watson iot dashboard

Tags: ibm, iot

Вариант с подключением хранилища, который описан в документации уже не актуален. Наверное с сентября этого года.
Актуальной инструкции как подключить больше нет.
Получилось так:
создал сервис cloudant,
прописал data store connector как написано в
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP8H/iot/platform/reference/dsc/cloudant.html
Из сервиса iot в базу, данные стали писаться, а вот на вкладке extensions база так и не появились.
При создании card в dashboard тоже пишет:
`"Cloudant instance No databases have being configured in the extensions page"`.
Что ещё нужно? Документация на английском, разобраться в ней не удается.